# What is the opposite of a regular curve?

Tags: differential-geometry, curves

The definition in Wikipedia is:

The curve $\gamma: I \to \mathbb R^n$ $r$-times continuously differentiable with $I$ a non-empty interval of real numbers is regular of order $m$ (where $m\leq r)$ if, for every $t\in I,$

$$\{\gamma'(t), \gamma''(t),\cdots,\gamma^{(m)}(t)\}$$

is a linearly independent subset of $\mathbb R^n.$ In particular, a parametric $C^1$-curve $\gamma$ is regular iff $\gamma'(t)\neq \mathbf 0$ for any $t\in I.$

Does this imply that a particle moving through the curve constantly changes velocity? What is the motivation of this definition? What is the opposite of a regular curve?

Comment: You should add the condition that $m\le n$. It is also unclear what you mean by "opposite." Like, what would be your notion of "opposite" to differentiable? Noweher differentiable? For $m=n$, "regular" curves are called **hyperconvex** and this is a generalization of the classical convexity condition.

Comment: @MoisheKohan I was looking for a counterexample.

Comment: Oh, I see, that was unclear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the $C^1$ curve $\gamma\colon I\to\mathbb R^n$ is regular, then by definition, $\gamma'\left(x\right)\ne\mathbf 0$ for all $x\in I$. This means that curve $\gamma$ never "slows down" to stop.

For example, constant curve $\gamma_1\left(t\right)=\mathrm{x}_0$ is not regular because $\gamma'_1=\mathbf 0$. On the other hand, straight line $\gamma_2\left(t\right)=\mathrm x_0 + t\cdot \mathrm x_1$ where $\mathrm x_1\ne \mathbf 0$ is regular because $\gamma_2'=\mathrm x_1\ne\mathbf 0$. This curve is not regular of order 2 (2-regular) because $\gamma_2''=\mathbf 0$. Circle, $\gamma_3\left(t\right)=\left(\cos t, \sin t\right)$, is regular of order 2. Notice that all three curves are $C^{\infty}$.

Comment: My statement was 'constantly changes velocity', not 'doesn't change velocity'.

Comment: Sorry, I deleted now that part of my answer. But yes, if $\gamma''\ne\mathbf 0$ then $\gamma'$ is not constant.

Comment: Definition of regular curve is important when we want to introduce Frenet–Serret basis.

Comment: How is it important for the TNB frame?

Comment: You can't construct (unique) TN frame if curve is not regular. You cant construct (unique) TNB frame if curve is not regular of order 2. In general, to construct Frenet–Serret frame in $\mathbb R^n$ you need $n-1$ regular curve.